# Android : Access one class variable data in another(by file or public variable)

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I'm trying to get data from my mysql database into android app, so it can be used even when the phone is not connected to internet. For it, I use asynctask to run in background. Now the problem is that this code is written in other class, and the data is stored in a variable in that class. So I'm not able to access the contents of that variable outside the class at all. I have tried everything, like assigning it to a static variable of same type which is of other class, writing the data to file, sharedpreferences,  but since the code is actually in a sort of function, I get errors with file operations and shared preferences. My code is as belows:
    public static boolean flag = false, otpStatus = false,otpcheckDone = false;
    public static SingleUser fromClient, fromServer;
    public static String resp;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

```
public static class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (getUserData) {
            getUserData = false;
            String METHOD_NAME = "user";
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(
                    CommonData.NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    CommonData.URL);
            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                resp = resultsRequestSOAP
                        .getPrimitivePropertyAsString("return");
                upd = (UpdateData) stringToObject(resp);
                MainActivity.upd = upd;
                LoginActivity.setupd((UpdateData) stringToObject(resp));
                LoginActivity.upd = upd;
                addtoDatabase ad =new addtoDatabase(null, null, null, 1);
                addtoDatabase.firstTime=true;
                ad.addData(upd);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do note that the UpdateData is a class accessed from a library file. Rest all works fine, I get response and all, but I'm just not able to access the variable,here 'upd', outside anywhere. As You can see, I have tried storing it in another class 'LoginActivity' variable LoginActivity.upd, but even that says that the object is null, although I can see the data in original "upd" when I do sysout.

So I need a way to access the data in "upd" variable outside the class.
I call the function using:

```
CommonData.getUserData=true;
lo = new LongOperation();
lo.execute("");
```